# dynamical key & mongodb unclarities

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

```
let time = "12:00";

"10:00": {
  name: "john",
  status: "registered"
},
"11:00": {
  name: "jane",
  status: "pending"
},
"12:00": {
  name: "joe",
  status: "denied"
}
```

how to `find()` the data in mongodb by its dynamically changing key variable (`time` in this case)?
also how to access the name key afterwards like in plain javascript (`someVar[time].name`) as with the results of `find().toArray` I can't really do that ... and `storedJson[2].name` after `storedJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))` storing the result of `dbo.collection(someCollection).find({}, { projection: { _id: 0} }).toArray ( (err, result)` seems a bit off and not how this should be done ... (also curious if it unwise saving data that way - and would therefore be open for an suggested alternative)

EDIT:

```
time: [time],
   content: {
      name: "john",
      status: "pending"
   }
```

this also isn't really a case since as I'm struggling grasping the `.toArray` which forces me to do `someVar[0].content.name` instead of `someVar[time].content.name`

Comment: Saving _any_ data as field names is widely considered an anti-pattern with MongoDB.  As you have found, it leads to a query nightmare.  There are many options, but a data model something like `"event": {"time": BSON Date, "name": "fred", "status": "qwerty"}` will allow for much simpler queries.